# Select Multiple Views while dragging finger in android

Tags: java, android

I have created multiple views dynamically , in my case `textViews`. i have given them ids. what iwant is to select all the `textViews` ids over which i `slide my finger`. E.g if there are textviews saying A And B and when i slide finger from A to b i should get ids save in my array. Currently I am learning touch. I don't know how to implement it.

Best Regards

```
  OnTouchListener MyOnTouchListener = new OnTouchListener(){ 
          public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) 
          {
              Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.small_corners);
              switch(event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK){
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                           vibe.vibrate(20);


                               id.add(v.getId());   
                               TextView vv = (TextView) v;
                               val.add(vv.getText().toString()); 
                               vv.setBackgroundDrawable(d);
                               String str = "";



            //A pressed gesture has started, the motion contains the initial starting location.
            return false;
           case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
            //A non-primary pointer has gone down.
            break;
           case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            //A change has happened during a press gesture (between ACTION_DOWN and ACTION_UP).
               int check = 0;
               for (int i = 0; i < id.size(); i ++)
               {
                   if (id.get(i) == v.getId())
                       check = 1;
               }
               if (check != 1)
               {
                   id.add(v.getId());
                   vv = (TextView) v;
                   val.add(vv.getText().toString()); 
                   vv.setBackgroundDrawable(d);
               }
            return false;
           case MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK:
                //A change has happened during a press gesture (between ACTION_DOWN and ACTION_UP).

                break;
           case MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE:
                //A change has happened during a press gesture (between ACTION_DOWN and ACTION_UP).

                break;


           case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            //A pressed gesture has finished.

              break;

           case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
            //A non-primary pointer has gone up.

            break;
           }

           return false;
          }
         };
```

Comment: See here

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21872464/get-button-coordinates-and-detect-if-finger-is-over-them-android][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21872464/get-button-coordinates-and-detect-if-finger-is-over-them-android

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried [ACTION_HOVER_ENTER](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#ACTION_HOVER_ENTER) and ACTION_HOVER_EXIT?
It might do the trick. See example in documentation of [onGenericMotionEvent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onGenericMotionEvent%28android.view.MotionEvent%29).

Comment: idont  get it, how will i set this generic motion with my textView

Answer (score 0):

From what I have understood, try this; Implement `onTouchlistner` and set this listener for all of your `TextView`s, in `onTouch()` do this:

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){
            //SAVE YOUR VIEWS ID//
            someArray[index] = ((TextView)v).getId()) 
            return true;
     }
     return false;
}
```

Try different `ACTIONS` of `MotionEvent`