# Get button coordinates and detect if finger is over them - Android

Tags: java, android, motionevent

I have 4 buttons in my android app activity. This is what it looks like:
 
[image]

As you can see, the textViews at the bottom of the screen display the x and y coordinates. The coordinates are in reference to a relative layout. (See below given code)

Now, what I want to do is get the x and y coordinates of the 4 buttons at runtime and then figure out if my finger is touching the buttons while moving or not. In simple words, I want to press the buttons by swiping my finger over them instead of lifting and touching. How can I achieve it? I want to implement it in my piano application.

I was able to get the coordinates on screen and they change as I move my finger.
So, my question is **How can I get the coordinates of the buttons and detect if my finger is swiping above them?**:
**XML**

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#ffffff"
android:id="@+id/relativelayout">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Y Cord : "
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="X Cord : "
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final TextView xcordview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
    final TextView ycordview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    RelativeLayout touchview = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativelayout);
    touchview.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            xcordview.setText(String.valueOf(event.getX()));
            ycordview.setText(String.valueOf(event.getY()));
            return true;
        }
    });

  }
}
```

Thank you all very very much!

Update:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
RelativeLayout touchview;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final TextView xcordview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
    final TextView ycordview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    touchview = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativelayout);
    touchview.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            xcordview.setText(String.valueOf(event.getX()));
            ycordview.setText(String.valueOf(event.getY()));
            for(int i = 0; i < touchview.getChildCount(); i++){
                if(checkInterSection(touchview.getChildAt(i), event.getRawX(), event.getRawY())){
                    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
                    button.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                    break;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    });

}
private boolean checkInterSection(View view, float rawX, float rawY) {
    int[] location = new int[2];
    view.getLocationOnScreen(location);
    int x = location[0];
    int y = location[1];
    int width = view.getWidth();
    int height = view.getHeight();
    //Check the intersection of point with rectangle achieved
    return (!(rawX < x || rawY > x + width || rawY < y || rawY > y + height));
}

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
package com.example.touch;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button b1, b2, b3, b4;

    int b1x1, b1x2, b1y1, b1y2;

    private TextView xcordview;
    private TextView ycordview;
    private TextView buttonIndicator;
    private RelativeLayout touchview;
    private static int defaultStates[];
    private Button mLastButton;
    private final static int[] STATE_PRESSED = {
            android.R.attr.state_pressed,
            android.R.attr.state_focused  
                    | android.R.attr.state_enabled };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        xcordview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        ycordview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        buttonIndicator = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.button_indicator);
        touchview = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativelayout);

        b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        b3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        b4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
        defaultStates = b1.getBackground().getState();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();

        touchview.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            private boolean isInside = false;

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                int x = (int) event.getX();
                int y = (int) event.getY();

                xcordview.setText(String.valueOf(x));
                ycordview.setText(String.valueOf(y));

                for (int i = 0; i < touchview.getChildCount(); i++) {
                    View current = touchview.getChildAt(i);
                    if (current instanceof Button) {
                        Button b = (Button) current;

                        if (!isPointWithin(x, y, b.getLeft(), b.getRight(), b.getTop(),
                                b.getBottom())) {
                            b.getBackground().setState(defaultStates);
                        }

                        if (isPointWithin(x, y, b.getLeft(), b.getRight(), b.getTop(),
                                b.getBottom())) {
                            b.getBackground().setState(STATE_PRESSED);
                            if (b != mLastButton) {
                                mLastButton = b;
                                buttonIndicator.setText(mLastButton.getText());
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }
                return true;
            }

        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    }

    static boolean isPointWithin(int x, int y, int x1, int x2, int y1, int y2) {
        return (x <= x2 && x >= x1 && y <= y2 && y >= y1);
    }
}
```

layout file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relativelayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:text="Y Cord : "
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:text="X Cord : "
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="B1"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
        android:text="B2"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
        android:text="B3"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button3"
        android:text="B4"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/button_indicator"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_marginRight="33dp"
        android:text="No one"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button_indicator"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button_indicator"
        android:layout_marginRight="29dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button_indicator"
        android:text="Entered: "
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks! But whats simple math? Can u please provide the code for me to better understand?

Comment: like for first button y should between getLeft() and getRight()

Comment: please see my answer above

Comment: Can you please help me? There is a slight error in your code. When I move my finger from the white space into the button, it recognizes the button perfectly. But when i put my finger on the button, and then move it to another button, it doesn't work. Please please help me! I am really almost done completing my application!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47925/discussion-between-arjun-9990-and-droidfan)

Answer (score 4):

```
private boolean checkInterSection(View view, int rawX, int raxY) {
    int[] location = new int[2];
    view.getLocationOnScreen(location);
    int x = location[0];
    int y = location[1];
    int width = view.getWidth();
    int height = view.getHeight();
    //Check the intersection of point with rectangle achieved 
    return (!(rawX < x || rawY > x + width || rawY < y || rawY > y + height)); 
}

for(int i = 0; i < touchview.getChildCount(); i++){
    if(checkInterSection(touchview.getChildAt(i), event.getRawX(), event.getRawY())){
        if(checkInterSection(touchview.getChildAt(i), event.getRawX(), event.getRawY())){
            ((Button)touchview.getChildAt(i)).setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);// Type casting may not be required 
        }else{
            ((Button)touchview.getChildAt(i)).setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

getX() getY() for a OnTouchListener give coordinates relative the the cooresponding view.

If you prefer screen coordinates instead you can use one of the following

- overwrite onTouchEvent for the activity **and remove OnTouchListener-s for buttons**,
  in which case MotionEvent will report screen coordinates instead of Button coordinates

  > ```
  >    @Override 
  >    public boolean onTouchEvent (MotionEvent event) {
  >        xcordview.setText(String.valueOf(event.getX()));
  >        ycordview.setText(String.valueOf(event.getY()));
  >        return true;
  >    }
  > ```
- use getTop() getLeft() in OnTouchListener for a button:

  > ```
  >   touchview.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
  >     @Override
  >     public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
  >         xcordview.setText(String.valueOf(event.getX()+v.getLeft()));
  >         ycordview.setText(String.valueOf(event.getY()+v.getTop()));
  >         return true;
  >     }
  > });
  > ```

You may consider using [GestureDetector](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.html) to detect swipes, however it isn't really necessary.

Comment: Can you please provide code for both of your solutions so that I can  better understand it?

Comment: I guess there's some mistake! The first solution which you provided has the same code from my question!

Answer (score 0):

[karioki](/questions/tagged/karioki) 's solution works well. In order to make it work even when we start the move from inside one of the buttons, just add

> android:clickable="false"

for every button in xml.